# Suppose that a machine has 48-bit virtual addresses and 32-bit physical addresses

Tags: paging, tlb

Suppose that a machine has 48-bit virtual addresses and 32-bit physical addresses.

(a)  If pages are 4 KB, how many entries are in  the page table if it has only a single level?

12 bit offset so 2^36?
I feel that this is wrong. Can someone please explain this to me?

(b) Suppose this same system has a TLB (Translation Lookaside  Buffer) with 32 entries. Furthermore, suppose that a program contains instructions that fit into one page and it sequentially reads long integer elements from an array that spans thousands of pages. How effective will the TLB be for this case?

Answer (score 3):

For (a), yes, you're right. It's 2^36. 12 bits for an address within a page and 36 bits for a page number. The virtual address doesn't have any ways to assign bits.
The original solution is presented in "Modern Operating Systems, 4th edition, Problem Solutions" by Tanenbaum and I think it contains a mistake.

Here's another task by Tanenbaum:

> A machine has 48-bit virtual addresses and 32-bit physical addresses. Pages are 8 KB.
>   How many entries are needed for a single-level linear page table?

And the Answer (in the same book):

> With **8-KB** pages and a **48-bit** virtual address space, the number of virtual
>   pages is 2^48/2^13, which is 2^35 (about 34 billion).

Answer (score 2):

(a) We need one entry for each page, or 2^24 = 16 × 1024 × 1024 entries, since
there are 36 = 48 − 12 bits in the page number field.

(b) Instruction addresses will hit 100% in the TLB. The data pages will have a
100 hit rate until the program has moved onto the next data page. Since a
4-KB page contains 1,024 long integers, there will be one TLB miss and
one extra memory access for every 1,024 data references.

Comment: could you elaborate b answer as one TLB miss and TLB has 100% hit.